# How to convert shortcodes similar to wordpress?

Tags: php, str-replace

So our users write articles, to embed PDFs they generate a shortcode, so they don't have to know how to write iframes/html5 objects.

The original string would look like this:

```
$string= "Hello, view this pdf [PDF='hello.pdf'] 
and then view this PDF [PDF='goodmorning.pdf']";
```

Need to output

```
 ' Hello, view this pdf  <object data="https://myurl.com/media/hello.pdf" class="pdf-shortcode-
  iframe" type="application/pdf">
  <iframe class="pdf-shortcode-iframe" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?
  url=https://myurl.com/media/hello.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
   </object>
   and then view this PDF
  <object data="https://myurl.com/media/goodmorning.pdf" class="pdf-
    shortcode-iframe" type="application/pdf">
   <iframe class="pdf-shortcode-iframe" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?
   url=https://myurl.com/media/hello.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
    </object>
```

I tried running a string replace on the " [PDF='" and "'] " part of the shortcode but because each shortcode needs to be replaced with an object AND iframe inside of it, it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Show us the code you tried so far. We won't write the code for you, but we'll try help you fix the code you've written so far.

Comment: Basically something like the following:

Comment: @TreyTyler please try https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wasn't a very complex regex at all.... :-)

```
$re = '/(.*?)(\[\w{3}=\')(\w+\.\w+)(\'\])(.*?)(\[\w{3}=\')(\w+\.\w+).*/s';

$str = 'Hello, view this pdf [PDF=\'hello.pdf\'] 
and then view this PDF [PDF=\'goodmorning.pdf\']';


$subst = '$1 <object data="https://myurl.com/media/$3"  class="pdf-shortcode-iframe" type="application/pdf">  <iframe class="pdf-shortcode-iframe" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://myurl.com/media/$3&embedded=true"></iframe>   </object>$5 <object data="https://myurl.com/media/$7" class="pdf-shortcode-iframe" type="application/pdf">   <iframe class="pdf-shortcode-iframe" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://myurl.com/media/$3&embedded=true"></iframe>    </object>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

https://3v4l.org/9oIpv
Or on regex101 https://regex101.com/r/MZV6ym/1

The only real explenation I can give is that it matches all parts of the message and replaces it with what you want.
I made it only notice three letter extensions with this parts here: `(\[\w{3}=\')` (keep in mind there is two of them in the regex in case you want to change it) it can be changed to {3,4} in case you want to include three and four letter extensions.
Or you can just make it \w+ and it will match all, but that can mean it will pick up wrong matches.

> Edit; sorry didn't notice that regex101 code generator escaped the " automatically. I had to first remove my escaping, and then I noticed no escaping at all was needed, so I had to remove another escape.

Edit2; I will try to explain the regex a bit better since you wrote you don't know regex.

Preg_replace needs one pattern or also called regex `$re`, one substitution pattern `$subst` and a input string `$str`.
The regex contains instructions on what to look for, so instead of looking for "hello.pdf" I can look for a `word.word`for example. Or only digits etc.
Regex is very good when you need to learn a computer how to read complex text that humans can easily find.

The pattern I use is:

```
/ is delimiter that must be used in regex, you can use ~, #, + and some more.
() The paranthese means capture as in save this. And in this regex there is a few needed.
(.*?) capture anything that is zero or more in lenght. The ? means be lazy and stop as soon as the next pattern is true.
(\[\w{3}=\') Capture [ and a word with three letters a = and '. I need to escape some signs as they are part of regex patterns
(\w+\.\w+) this captures a word of one or more letters followed by a dot and a word again of one or more letters.
(\'\]) Capture the ' and ]. I only do this so that I can filter them out of the result string.
(.*?) again capture anything that is zero or more in lenght. This is to capture the second line starting with "and then"

And then there is a repetition of the finding file name.

/ end delimiter 
s this is a setting to make a dot match a new line (multi line setting)
```

The substitution is a lot easier to understand.
All the captures () from the pattern is numbered from left to right.
$0 is the full original string so this one is more for reference.
$1 is the first capture, in the pattern used that equals to (.*?) or "Hello,..."
$2 will hold the second capture= "[PDF=\'"

and so on.

So with these captures you build your substitution string.

As a final note.
It may seem as regex is perfect and works for everything, but please. Try to use it as little as possible.
Here on SO it seems "everyone" use regex for the simplest of tasks and that is not what regex was meant for.
Regex is meant for complex and none static strings (such as yours), when you don't know if the "number" you are looking for is 1 or 1000. Or if the word you are looking for is at position 4 or 50 and what it's lenght is.
That is when regex works the best.

Regex takes a long time compared with conventional php and uses more memory.
That is why I mean regex should be saved for those special occasions.

Comment: Wow! This worked perfectly!!!! I have yet to learn REGEX but now I can see how handy it really is

Comment: @TreyTyler I added some more information about the regex since you say you don't know regex. I went to bed as soon as I had written the answer to you last night, that is why I was "short" on the explenation.

Comment: Thanks Andreas this explanation is awesome.  I much better understand what it does! Still a tad confused, it's a lot more complex than just a simple str_replace. Going to research this one all morning I think there's some times this could have come in handy!

Comment: @Trey well you will get there. Preg_replace is harder than preg_match since you have a replacement to. If you use a online service as regex101 as I linked to above or http://www.phpliveregex.com then you will be able to see what happens as you type the pattern. Liveregex even have a list of "how to use it" below.